# Can't run wso2 esb after doing wso2 mb tutorial

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I'm trying to catch up with the new realease of the wso2ei 7 and 'm following the new [tutorial](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/tutorials/storing-and-forwarding-messages/) but I keep getting an error when I start the esb again with the following error

> Store [PaymentRequestMessageStore]. Could not initialize JMS Message Store. Error:Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hash table.. Initial Context Factory:[org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory]; Provider URL:[null]; Connection Factory:[null]. javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hash table. [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory not found]
>       at org.wso2.micro.core.context.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:301)
>       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:681)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:216)
>
> ...

Can anyone help me with that?

[EDIT]

I started the esb from the cmd and i got a diferent error, I don't know if helps or not...

> ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager} - Error setting up connection factory : myQueueSender org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.AxisJMSException: Cannot acquire JNDI context, JMS Connection factory : QueueConnectionFactory or default destination : null for JMS CF : myQueueSender using : {transport.jms.CacheLevel=producer, broker_name=wso2mb, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory, java.naming.provider.url=conf/jndi.properties}
>   at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.initJMSConnectionFactory(JMSConnectionFactory.java:188)
>   at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.(JMSConnectionFactory.java:152)
>   at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager.loadConnectionFactoryDefinitions(JMSConnectionFactoryManager.java:89)
>   ...

Comment: Can you send the link of the tutorial you are trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working through the EI [Asynchronous Messaging](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/tutorials/storing-and-forwarding-messages/) tutorial, you will get this ClassNotFound exception if you don't do the following first:

Download WSO2 Message Broker. The path to this folder is referred to as MB_HOME throughout this tutorial.

**Add the following JAR files from the MB_HOME/wso2/broker/client-lib/ directory to the MI_TOOLING_HOME/Contents/Eclipse/runtime/microesb/lib/ (in MacOS) or MI_TOOLING_HOME/runtime/microesb/lib (in Windows) directory.**

**andes-client-*.jar**

**geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-*.jar**

**org.wso2.securevault-*.jar**

For me on OSX, the MI_TOOLING_HOME is /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app.